# How to import remote csv file on a deployed shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, deployment

I try to create an shiny app that allows to upload csv data and manipulate them (simplified example).

When the app is not deployed, no problem to upload local csv throught shinyFilesButton:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel(
    'Selections with shinyFiles',
    'shinyFiles example'
  ),
  sidebarPanel(
    shinyFilesButton('file', 'File select', 'Please select a file', FALSE)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tags$h4('The output of a file selection'),
    tableOutput("contents")
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  volumes = getVolumes()
  shinyFileChoose(input, 'file',  roots = volumes, filetypes=c('', 'csv'))
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    inFile <- parseFilePaths( roots = volumes, input$file)
    if( NROW(inFile)) {
      df <- read.csv(as.character(inFile$datapath))
    }
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

We clearly see all the stucture needed:  [image]

But when the app is deployed, impossible to find any file. Here is the deployed app: https://charlottesirot1985.shinyapps.io/Server/.

[image]

As I understand the app/server has no access to remote data ? Do I understand correctly ?Or maybe it is not the same "home" (I guess so...)

How to work around ?? How to work on remote data with deployed shiny app ?

Thanks in advance for your answer !

Charlotte

Comment: Are you really saying that you want your public-facing shiny app to have unfettered access to your local computer's files? There are a dozen reasons why this is a bad idea, and why it's hard to do even if it weren't such a bad idea. If you have files in your dev environment that you want users to be able to use, why not deploy them with the app?

Comment: Actually I was scared that it could be one big issue.. To answer your question about why not to put the data directly with the app, the reason is that each user may have different version of this file to upload. I guess I have to use a local solution. For users that are not Rusers, I will have to find a good trick ;) In any case, thanks a lot for your answer :)

Comment: Why don't you use `fileInput`?